# Styling every second, fifth, eighth item using CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a div with some entries in it. It is a 3 column and 3 rows grid:

My elements are in this order using flexbox:

[1]   **[2]**   [3]

[4]   **[5]**   [6]

[7]   **[8]**   [9]

I want to find the css selector to style the 2nd, 5th, 8th (and so on) elements.

This is for a logo grid. Each number represents a logo element, but could also be used for anything else.

**HTML**

```html
<div class="entries-wrapper">
  <div class="entry">
    <img class="logo" src="/src/img/logo-1.svg">
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <img class="logo" src="/src/img/logo-2.svg">
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <img class="logo" src="/src/img/logo-3.svg">
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <img class="logo" src="/src/img/logo-4.svg">
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <img class="logo" src="/src/img/logo-5.svg">
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <img class="logo" src="/src/img/logo-6.svg">
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <img class="logo" src="/src/img/logo-7.svg">
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <img class="logo" src="/src/img/logo-8.svg">
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <img class="logo" src="/src/img/logo-9.svg">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.entries-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.entry {
    flex: 0 0 33.33%;
    margin: 0 0 38px !important;
}

.entry:nth-child(?n+?) img {
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
}
```

I want the 2nd, 5th, 8th img element to be centered instead of being aligned left.

I want to find a css-nth-child selector for the part 
**.entry:nth-child(?n+?)**

Comment: `.entry:nth-child(3n+2)` should do the job no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can determine the `an + b` equation that you need for `nth-child`.

### First

Figure out the 1-based indices of the elements you want to select. Fortunately for me, you've done this already with your handy diagram:

```
1 [2] 3
4 [5] 6
7 [8] 9
```

### Second

make a table of values

```
n | result
--+-------
0 | 2
1 | 5
2 | 8
```

Note that while the indices for the nodes are 1-based, `n` values are 0-based indices.

### Third

You want to solve the equation `a(n) + b = result`.

To do this, start by filling in the equation when `n` is zero.

```
a(n) + b = result // n = 0, result = 2
a(0) + b = 2
```

This will cancel out the `a` value, leaving you with:

```
b = 2
```

To make more progress, substitute different values for `n` and `result`:

```
a(n) + b = result
a(1) + 2 = 5 // n = 1, result = 5
      -2  -2 // subtract 2 from both sides

a(1) + 0 = 3 // simplify

       a = 3
```

We now have the equation

```
3(n) + 2 = result
```

### Finally

To verify we can substitute another set of values into the equation and double-check that it also produces a correct result:

```
a(n) + b = result
3(2) + 2 = 8 // a = 3, b = 2, n = 2, result = 8
   6 + 2 = 8 // multiply
       8 = 8 // add
// ✔︎ verified
```

Comment: // ✔︎ <-- lol, that made my day, and the good explanation

Comment: @zzzzBov Thank you! Since you provided the most background details I think your answer should be considered as the most valuable!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `3n+2`

```css
.entries-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.entry {
  flex: 0 0 33.33%;
  margin: 0 0 38px !important;
}

.entry:nth-child(3n+2) img {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="entries-wrapper">
  <div class="entry">
    <img class="logo" src="/src/img/logo-1.svg">
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <img class="logo" src="/src/img/logo-2.svg">
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <img class="logo" src="/src/img/logo-3.svg">
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <img class="logo" src="/src/img/logo-4.svg">
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <img class="logo" src="/src/img/logo-5.svg">
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <img class="logo" src="/src/img/logo-6.svg">
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <img class="logo" src="/src/img/logo-7.svg">
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <img class="logo" src="/src/img/logo-8.svg">
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <img class="logo" src="/src/img/logo-9.svg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the selector `.entry:nth-child(3n+2)`.

Explanation: This selector will select one element out of 3, starting from the 2nd one.

It's an [arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) with first term equal to `2` and difference between terms of `3`.

Answer (score 0):

```
.entries-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.entry {
    flex: 0 0 33.33%;
    margin: 0 0 38px !important;
}

.entry:nth-child(3n+2) img {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```